# Can someone help what is incorrect in this program?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
void func(int* ptr)
{
    ptr =  new int;
}

int main() 
{
    int* ptr;
    func(ptr);
    *ptr = 2;
}
```

This was one of the interview questions I faced. in main (), it is declaring an int pointer, allocating it memory in another function and trying to utilise in the main() itself. It is erroneous in some way I think, but how else should this work, any idea?

Comment: I think it should be using reference "&" on the funct parameter

Comment: You are not deleting the pointer anywhere. That's a memory leak.

Also, what others said, you need to pass the pointer by referecne(or ptr to ptr).

You really should initialize all local variables too (`int* ptr;` here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ptr` is passed to `funcn` by value so the parameter `ptr` only gets the copy of `ptr` in `main`. Any changes to `func`'s `ptr` would not modify `main`'s `ptr` and hence memory is not allocated for the pointer `ptr` in `main`. The assignment to uninitialized pointer

```
*ptr = 2;
```

invokes *undefined behavior*.

Possible solutions:

**Using pointer to pointer**:

```
void func(int** ptr)
{
    *ptr =  new int;
}

int main() 
{
    int* ptr;
    func(&ptr);
    *ptr = 2;
}
```

**Returning pointer from function:**

```
int* func(int* ptr)
{
    ptr =  new int;
}

int main() 
{
    int* ptr;
    ptr = func(ptr);
    *ptr = 2;
}
```

**Using reference:**

```
void func(int&* ptr)
{
    ptr =  new int;
}

int main() 
{
    int* ptr;
    func(ptr);
    *ptr = 2;
}
```

Comment: In the pointer to pointer example, `func`'s body should look like ` *ptr = new int;` shouldn't it?

Comment: In the 'returning pointer from function' example, should the func return ptr after allocating memory?

Comment: @SwappyCplusplus; Yes. You need to allocate it first.

Answer (score 1):

```
void func(int&* ptr)
{
    ptr =  new int;
}

int main() 
{
    int* ptr;
    func(ptr);
    *ptr = 2;
}
```

pass pointer by reference, not  by value