# char "string" not updating in function

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I have a function which looks like:

```
void myFunc(char* myString, char* const buf, int startPos){
    myString = &buf[startPos];
    std::cout << myString << std::endl;     //This outputs fine
}
```

.
.
.
.

```
char* myString = 0;
.
.
myFunc(myString, buf, startPos);
std::cout << myString << std::endl;         //This doesnt output anything
```

Why doesn't printing out the string work after I have made the function call?

Comment: `myString` is a local variable in `myFunc`. The caller won't see any modifications to it. Pass it by reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [pass by reference and value with pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776010/pass-by-reference-and-value-with-pointers)

Comment: @juanchopanza I thought passing a pointer achieved the same result as passing by reference? Otherwise what is the point of passing a pointer, ever?

Comment: Pass a pointer to modify **what it points to**, not to modify the pointer itself.

Comment: The problem is you'd need to pass a pointer to the pointer to modify the pointer itself, rather than what it points to :)

Comment: I looked at the "possible duplicate" link and that recommended char &* (because they gave an example of using int &*) but the compiler complains I cannot do that....

Comment: Is it possible to do this using a reference? I'd like to copy as little as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call

```
myFunc(myString, buf, startPos);
```

`myString` is copied to the function parameter. Any changes to the pointer `myString` does not change the pointer `myString` in `main`.

Either use `char **mystring` in function parameter or pass `myString` by reference.

```
void myFunc(char&* myString, char* const buf, int startPos){...}
```

Comment: How would passing myString by reference work? I didn't think it would be char& because that would just be one byte?

Comment: @user997112; Updated the answer. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24388287/2455888) too.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the function return the value of mystring?

```
char* myFunc(char* myString, char* const buf, int startPos){
    myString = &buf[startPos];
    std::cout << myString << std::endl;     //This outputs fine
    return myString;
}
```

Then print the value:

```
std::cout << myFunc(myString, buf, startPos) << std::endl;
```

Or, you could do:

```
myString = myFunc(myString, buf, startPos);
std::cout << myString << std::endl;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to modify something in a function, you have to pass a pointer to that "thing"... in this case, your "thing" is a "pointer-to-char" so you need to pass in a "pointer-to-'pointer-to-char'", so:

```
void myFunc(char** myString, char* const buf, int startPos){
    *myString = &buf[startPos];
    std::cout << *myString << std::endl;     //This outputs fine
}
```

and call it with:

```
myFunc(&myString, buf, startPos);
```

The `&myString` takes the address of your "pointer-to-char" which will allow the function to modify it; inside the function, you need the extra `*`s to dereference this address and get to the value you want to change.